# Solving a many to many relationship between tables that get data from another table

Tags: mysql, many-to-many

My problem involves 4 tables defined int he code below: workers, teams, old_table, production

```
create table if not exists workers(
id_worker int auto_increment primary key,
name_worker varchar(50),
firstname_worker varchar(50),
constraint fullname_worker UNIQUE (name_worker, firstname_worker)
);

create table if not exists teams(
id_team int auto_increment primary key,
name_boss_team varchar(50),
firstname_boss_team varchar(50),
constraint fullname_boss_team UNIQUE (name_boss_team, firstname_boss_team)
);

create table if not exists production(
id_production int auto_increment primary key,
date_hour datetime,
id_boss_team_fk int,
id_worker_fk int,
quantity int default 0,
FOREIGN KEY (id_worker_fk) REFERENCES workers(id_worker),
FOREIGN KEY (id_boss_team_fk) REFERENCES teams(id_team)

);

create table old_table(
date1 varchar(50),
hour varchar(50),
name_wrk varchar(50),
firstname_wrk varchar(50),
name_boss varchar(50),
firstname_boss varchar(50),
no_of_parts int,
fulldate datetime default null

);
```

**OBS:** *wrk stands for worker*

The data is initially imported into the old_table from a txt file.
In the production table I must have the worker id, the team id No_of_parts and fulldate.
I tried to populate the foreign key columns but I only managed to populate one while the other got populated only with NULL values.

I used the lines below to insert a column from the old_table into the production table in order to be able to lionk them for the join instruction:

```
insert into production(date_hour)
select fulldate from old_table;
```

Then, I created my update instruction:

```
 update production
set id_worker_fk = 
(select id_worker from workers
join old_table on name_worker = name_wrk and firstname_worker = firstname_wrk
join production on fulldate =(select date_hour from production));
```

But this is clearly not right since it is not working.

Does anyone know how my problem should be approached?

Comment: _"Does anyone know how my problem should be approached?"_ Doubtful, the CREATEs you've provided are incomplete, and you neglected to provide the query you used to make the attempt.

Comment: The missing line from the table creation was generated by a typo of mine and I initially did not include the query because I am not sure that it is even close to how it should be.

Comment: Even if your attempt is totally wrong, often it can explain what you are trying better than paragraphs of description.

Comment: Performance tips for many-to-many tables:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table

Answer (score 0):

The layers of subqueries make it a little hard to be sure, but it looks to me like you can accomplish the task by having the initial `INSERT SELECT` include the join logic as well.

```
INSERT INTO production (date_hour, id_worker_fk)
SELECT o.fulldate
FROM old_table AS o
LEFT JOIN workers AS w 
    ON o.name_wrk = w.name_worker AND o.firstname_wrk = w.firstname_worker
```